# Where are validators exhaustively listed for Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, documentation

I can see some validators listed in the Rails Guides for 3.2 [3 Validation Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers), but I assume they don't list everything there, because there aren't any about capitalisation, and you can't list everything in the Rails guides.

[APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) documentation on `validates` provides examples of invocation of Rails validators, but doesn't have any detailed documentation.

Where are validators exhaustively listed for Rails 3.2?

Comment: Pretty sure they're all there in the guides.   There are no capitalization-related validations in Rails.

Comment: I would just check the source code, there's no source more authoritative than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A place to start is in the `ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods` [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html).

From there, you can also read through:
- [ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html)
- [ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks.html)